# Issues with regular expression in matching Urls

Tags: regex

I am using the regular expression below for matching YouTube URLs

```
(?:http?s?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:.*v(?:\/|=)|(?:.*\/)?)([\w'-]+))
```

This URL matched every URL but if URL is written in let say `<p>` tag then it matches the last closing `p` tag `</p>` for this URL `http://youtu.be/-wtIMTCHWuI`.

**Demo html :**

```
<p>Lesson Description, Video testing.</p>

<p> </p>

<p>http://youtu.be/-wtIMTCHWuI</p>
```

If you match the above HTML with the regular expression above, the result will be:

`http://youtu.be/-wtIMTCHWuI</p`

which is wrong, I do not want the last closing `</p>`.

If I modify the regex and write `(?=<)` in the end then it works fine but then it will not work for other YouTube URLs like `http://www.youtube.com/v/-wtIMTCHWuI?version=3`. It only includes `?version=3` in the end.

Without `(?=<)` it will match `http://www.youtube.com/v/-wtIMTCHWuI` in `http://www.youtube.com/v/-wtIMTCHWuI?version=3` but with this `(?=<)` it matches nothing.

I hope I have explained my question correctly. What will be the right regex which will match above URLs and do not match HTML tags `</p>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `?` and `=` symbols inside the last character class and also you need to make `(?:.*\/)?` to `(?:[^<]*\/)?` because `.*` is greedy by default. That is, it would match all the characters as much as possible. `[^<]*` matches any character but not of `<`, zero or more times.

```
(?:http?s?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:.*\bv(?:\/|=)|(?:[^<]*\/)?)(?:[\w'?=-]+))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/21)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:http?s?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:.*v(?:\/|=)|(?:[^<]*\/)?)(?:[\w'-]+))
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/20

Comment: yes it is working, But its not including format after `?` like `?version=3&autohide=1` in `http://www.youtube.com/v/-wtIMTCHWuI?version=3&autohide=1`